# Single perceptron keeps outputting values close 0.5

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am trying to create the simplest perception there is with just one neuron (neuron takes 2 input values and * them by weights then + bias and activate the SUM of them with (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x))) sigmoid function ) and train it via backpropagation (get an error by subtracting expected value from the output I gain, find gradient and weight delta by which we multiply the difference between wight and input value), but after the first iteration, my weights get really close to 0 and start producing a sigmoid(0) which is 0.5 (it always produces values from 0.48 to 0.52 or close.

```
class Neuron {constructor(){
    this.inputs = [1,1];
    this.inputWeights = [(Math.random()*2)-1,(Math.random()*2)-1];
    this.bias = 0.1;
    this.activate = () => {
        if(this.inputs.length !== this.inputWeights.length)return "Wrong input length";
        let sum = 0;
        for(var n = 0; n < this.inputs.length;n++){
        sum = sum + (this.inputs[n]*this.inputWeights[n]);      
        }
        sum = sum + this.bias;
        //return sigmoid activated value
        let activated_output = (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-sum)));
        return activated_output;
    };
    this.error = (predicted,desired) => {
        let error = predicted - desired;
        let gradient = predicted * (1-predicted);
        let weights_delta = error * gradient;
        return weights_delta;
    };
    this.changeWeights = (weights_delta) => {
        let info = this.inputWeights[0];
        for(var n = 0; n < this.inputWeights.length; n++){
            this.inputWeights[n] = (this.inputWeights[n] - this.inputs[n])  * weights_delta * learning_rate;
        }
        return "first weight changed from " + info + " to " + this.inputWeights[0];
    }
}}
var testNeuron = new Neuron();
var learning_rate = 0.05;
var dataset = [
{ inputs: [1,0], outputs: [1] },
{ inputs: [0,1], outputs: [0] }, 
{ inputs: [0.5,0.1], outputs: [1] },
{ inputs: [0.1,0.9], outputs: [0] }];
//train
var train = (iterations, data) => {
  for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
    for(var n = 0; n < data.length; n++){
    testNeuron.inputs = data[n].inputs;
    console.log(testNeuron.changeWeights(testNeuron.error(testNeuron.activate() , 
data[n].outputs[0])));
    }
  }
}
train(10,dataset);
```

Here is all the code, I tryed it with and without biases but i feel my math is definitely wrong but I could not figure out where because I'm a noob..halp sirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest error was that I didn't use any bias input, and did not adjust weights for it. If we don't use bias then a simple input like 0,0 will ALWAYS return 0 and there is no way to adjust weights for output to change.

Second, if we looking at simple Perceptron we should be using a threshold function and not a sigmoid.(although sigmoid is possible but imo slower in this example) Thresh hold function is a simple function that returns 0 if output is negative and 1 if it's positive.
 My redone and working code looks like this, increasing training iteration results in a decrease of error just like it should, Thank you

```
class Perceptron{constructor(){
    //bias , input1, input2
    this.inputs = [1,0,0];
    this.inputWeights = [(Math.random()*2)-1,(Math.random()*2)-1,(Math.random()*2)-1];
    this.output = 0;
    this.desiredOutput = 0; 
}//perceptron methods
    activate = () => {
        let sum = 0;
        for(var n = 0; n < this.inputs.length; n++){
            sum += this.inputs[n] * this.inputWeights[n];
        };
        this.output = sum < 0 ? 0 : 1;
        this.desiredOutput == this.output ? console.log("Correct answer") : console.log("Incorrect answer");
    };
    propagate = () => {
        let error = this.desiredOutput - this.output;
        for(var m = 0; m < this.inputs.length; m++){
            let delta = error * this.inputs[m];
            this.inputWeights[m] = this.inputWeights[m] + (delta * learningRate);
        } 
    };
}
let learningRate = 0.1;
var train = (iterations) => {
    for(var x = 0; x < iterations; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y < dataset.length; y++){
        perception.inputs = [1,dataset[y][0],dataset[y][1]];
        perception.desiredOutput = dataset[y][2];   
        perception.activate();
        perception.propagate(); 
        }
    }
}   
var perception = new Perceptron();
//[input1 , input2 , desiredOutput] 
var dataset = [
    [0,0,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [0.1,0.3,1],
    [1.5,1.8,0]
];  
train(100);
```